# How to interpret the preposition « à » in the following two instances

Tags: prépositions, verbes

While I have no problem understanding the meaning of these two sentences, the use of « à » wouldn’t come to mind if I were saying them myself.

> C'est ma faute, je suis désolé. On ne se serait pas fatigués **à** se battre pour rien dans le village sans ma brillante idée...

In the first example, can « à » be replaced with « à force de {by} »?

> La question, c'est plutôt de savoir ce que tu fabriques **à** filer comme un voleur...

I assume that the second example translates into "We should be asking instead what you’re up to, making off like a thief". But I’m not entirely certain how to interpret « à ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These ***à*** are not just (if at all) prepositions but infinitive markers although this concept is not yet established in French grammar.

While the most common marker is ***de***, some verbs like ***se fatiguer*** and ***fabriquer*** might use a ***à*** when followed by an infinitive.

> Je me fatigue **à** essayer **de** réparer le moteur.

but

> Ça me fatigue **d'** essayer **de** réparer le moteur.

See http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/464.html and http://gerflint.fr/Base/Paysscandinaves3/kalmbach.pdf from [Jean-Michel Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/0006.html) for details.

In the first example, replacing ***à*** with ***à force de*** will change the meaning of the sentence.

With ***à***, they are tired because they fight in the first place while with ***à force de***, they are tired because they fight for a substantial period of time.

Comment: Hi. Regarding the part "because they fight **in the first place**", do you mean "because they fight **for the first time**"?

Comment: No, not necessarily for the first time. I really mean "because they fight **in the first place**" using the idiom addressed here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86842/meaning-and-usage-of-the-phrase-in-the-first-place

Comment: So you would mean "**dû et seulement dû au fait que ...**" or "**à la base parce que ...**"?

Comment: The second choice. If that helps, I would have translated this sentence:  "My fault, I'm sorry. Without my brilliant idea, **we wouldn't have lost our energy fighting in vain** in the village." *Brilliant* is of course ironical here.

Comment: So I now see that in both of the two examples, "à + infinitif" translates into the "-ing" gerund in English. Do you imagine yourself rephrasing these sentences without having to use "à"? Or is the use of "à" absolutely necessary here? Merci.

Comment: As you mention gerund, here are alternatives without *à* : *On ne se serait pas fatigués en nous battant pour rien dans le village sans ma brillante idée...* and *La question, c'est plutôt de savoir ce que tu fabriques en filant comme un voleur...*

Answer (score 3):

I think we could translate you sentences like that :

> This is my fault, I'm sorry. We would have not get tired **by** fighting each
> other for nothing in the village without my good idea...
>
> the question, is to know what you're doing **by** getting away like a
> thief

Even if my english is a bit wrong the idea is still here and the translations are really close.
Anyway, in both case the **à** can be translate as **by**.

-- edit --

The **by** seems a bit forced, more accurately the "**-ing**" verb termination seems the best suited translation.